# Get second item of queryset in html file (Django)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

How can I get the second item of queryset in html file (Django)?[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I tried **{{ posts[1] }}**

**models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    videoLink = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='DEFAULT STRING')
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': list(posts)})
```

**My html**

> {{ posts[1] }}

Comment: you need to post your code instead of image

Comment: Please post code fragments, *not* images of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django templates use dot separated access, it will try to obtain the attribute, item, and the item of the integer conversion. You thus can obtain the second `Post` item with:

```
{{ posts.1 }}
```

Django templates deliberately do not allow function calls with parameters and subscripting however, since that usually means you are implementing *business logic* in the template. Usually deciding what to render is someting the view should decide, not the template. The template decide *how* to render something (in an nice way).

Comment: Thank you, but I have error
Invalid block tag on line 98: 'posts.1', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: @alcoder: You probably used `{% posts.1 %}` instead of `{{ posts.1 }}`. Notice the brackets.